# args in docker compose file is not passed to Dockerfile in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, docker

Hi I am passing a args value from docker-compose.yml file to Dockerfile. But it is not passing. Here i m sharing the code of what i have done.

Please suggest me

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    dev:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - APP_ENV=install
        ports:
            - 3006:3000
        volumes:
            - /var/app/node_modules
            - .:/var/app
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

ARG APP_ENV

WORKDIR /var/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm $APP_ENV

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
```

Comment: All instructions look OK. Is it a full example?
Maybe you use multistage dockerfile?

Comment: I'm getting same issue, the ARG in the docker file is not resolving to the arg specified in the docker-compose file... do you need to add anything when running docker-compose build   ???

Comment: Are you using docker for windows containers by any chance ?